# Unicode “undefined control sequence” in XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, errors, unicode, arabic, hebrew

I have got a TeXLive 2011 on an Apple Time Machine and TeXShop on my local MacBook.
When I try to typeset the XeLaTeX template from TeXShop, I get “undefined control sequence” for some of the Unicode text.

The relevant section of the template goes as follows:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}

\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Hoefler Text}
\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text]{Gill Sans}
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Andale Mono}

\begin{document}

\newfontfamily{\A}{Geeza Pro}
\newfontfamily{\H}[Scale=0.9]{Lucida Grande}
\newfontfamily{\J}[Scale=0.85]{Osaka}

Here are some multilingual Unicode fonts: this is Arabic text: {\A السلام عليكم},
this is Hebrew: {\H שלום}, 
and here's some Japanese: {\J 今日は}.

\end{document}
```

When I typeset this, I get:

```
./Untitled.tex:44: Undefined control sequence.
l.44 ...s: this is Arabic text: {\A \UTF
                                        {0627}\UTF{0644}\UTF{0633}\UTF{0644}...
```

Strangely, this occurs only for the Arabic and Hebrew texts, however, if I comment these out and leave only the Japanese section, the document is typeset without any errors and correct output.

At first, I thought that something was not passed correctly via the shell, but both bash and tcsh (used by TeXShop) return upon a `locale`:

```
LANG="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

I even tried adding `setenv LC_CTYPE en_US.UTF-8` (cf. [this](http://manual.macromates.com/en/bundles#setting_lc_ctype)) to the XeLaTeX engine for TeXShop but that did not help, either.

[This](http://pastebin.com/Xr7vmXWb) is the Log I get with the posted example.

I hope that you have any ideas concerning this problem.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you show also the preceding part of the preamble?

Comment: Added most of the remainder. Withheld part contained mostly comments, `maketitle` info and unused packages such as `graphicx` and `amssymb`.

Comment: Does your example really gives the error? If yes: show the log-file.

Comment: Added the link to my log as requested by @UlrikeFischer.

Comment: The log stops before showing the error. Did you end the compilation in the correct way?

Comment: Sorry, now I ran the compilation with the option to ignore all errors (`\scrollmode`, l. 857). I have uploaded the updated the log file.

Comment: Sorry again, I seem to have forgotten to add that I am running the TeXLive distribution on an Apple Time Capsule and accessing it locally with a MacBook running only the programs from “GUI-Applications.pkg” from MacTeX. I have added this information to the original question.

Comment: I would say your editor has exchanged the unicode chars by this \UTF-commands when saving the file. A search in the TeXshop forum came up with this advice: "Please UNCHECK TeXShop->Preferences->Misc->pTeX support-> utf export".

Comment: Thank you so much, that solved my problem. I feel kind of stupid, now that you pointed it out, because I had the feeling that I accidentally changed some of the settings when I installed the new version of TeXShop some time ago.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer You should make this as an answer. Unfortunately there's no way to reverse this process, AFAIK so Brian will have to retype the source.  You also need to restart TeXShop after changing the preferences.

Comment: @AlanMunn There was no harm done, I was just checking the system for any errors before actually using it for any work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would say your editor has exchanged the unicode chars by this \UTF-commands when saving the file. A search in the TeXshop forum came up with this advice: "Please UNCHECK TeXShop->Preferences->Misc->pTeX support-> utf export".